# Does Hibernate3 support filters for native queries?

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-filters

Does Hibernate3 support filters for native queries and if so can you please provide an example?

Answer (score 4):

No, hibernate3 doesn't support filters for native queries. If you run a native query in hibernate all enabled filters are simply ignored.

There's a ["New feature" request](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-626) for this, but it was issued in 2005 and it is still open.

Comment: 2016 it still open.

Comment: Is this still the case?